# Merging of audio and video by ffmpeg

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, ffmpeg, webm

I have 2 separate webm files - video and audio part. Now I want to merge it. I use python and ffmpeg

```
input_video = ffmpeg.input(f'{title}-video.webm').output("out1.webm")
input_audio = ffmpeg.input(f'{title}-audio.webm').output("out2.webm")
ffmpeg.merge_outputs(input_video, input_audio).run()
```

Output file looks OK (it plays audio and video) but it takes time to merge it. I guess there's a needless conversion that I could avoid. Is it possible to do with the given API?

I googled a command
ffmpeg -i 12m.mp4 -i 6m.mp4 -c copy -map 1:v -map 0:a -shortest new.mp4
 that should be run via command line, but I'd like to implement it by means of the API if it is possible.

Comment: In your example, ffmpeg will assume that `input_video` and `input_audio` both have audio and video components. It looks like you are using `ffmpeg-python`, if you add `.video` and `.audio` (respectively) to the pipeline does that help? See [Audio/video pipeline](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/tree/master/examples#audiovideo-pipeline)

Comment: @cherdt Do you mean _video = ffmpeg.input(f'{title}-video.webm').output("out1.webm").video
audio = ffmpeg.input(f'{title}-audio.webm').output("out2.webm").audio
ffmpeg.merge_outputs(video, audio).run()_

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just wondering if that speeds things up.

Comment: @cherdt no, it doesn't

Comment: @cherdt I tried to do it another way
  **video = ffmpeg.input(f'{filename}-video.webm').video
  audio = ffmpeg.input(f'{filename}-audio.webm').audio
  concatenated = ffmpeg.concat(video, audio, v=0, a=1)
  concatenated.output("output.webm", vcodec="copy", acodec="copy").run()**
Now I got an error _Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description [0:v][1:a]concat=a=1:n=2:v=0[s0] matches no streams._

Could you help please?